# TypeError : gfs.gracefulify is not a function + cordova OS X

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I was following every step in this link
[Cordova install OS X](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/guide/cli/index.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface)
but when I try to check cordova --version, it show me an error

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:19
```

, fs = gfs.gracefulify(require('fs'))

TypeError: gfs.gracefulify is not a function

Thanks

Comment: which version of node is install on your system?

Comment: I had the similar issue, but I installed Node 4.1.0 via `nvm` and that resolved it

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I upgraded to node 4.2.4 & npm 2.14.12, which didn't fix it. Please help

Answer (score 2):

You may goto the cordova's root directory(usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova) and do:

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 1):

Had this issue with ubuntu 15.10.

The problem is, that some packages come with their own node_modules directory and have an outdated npm-package (look also out for phonegap, has the same problem).

Goto

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/
```

rename the npm-directory to something else. After that Cordova should use the global (and hopefully correct) npm.

In general - if you run in trouble like this, look out if the subdir 'node_modules' is twice in the errorpath. You should remove or rename the package-dir in the subdirectory and rely on global package (after installing and updating it).

Answer (score 0):

I use Windows; same should work in Mac and Linux

npm in cordova wrong and cordova uses private npm

go to
C:\Users\sssca_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules
Rename npm to npm_XXX

Go to
C:\Users\sssca_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
This is where real npm resides
Copy npm directory from here to C:\Users\sssca_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules

It worked fine for me!